# Trying to run "ruby code" which is coming database and saved by user from the frontend. (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I am building the application where user can run ruby code modules from the client side
When code is saved it is saved in database, but when I am fetching the code to show file the code is just printing the string it's not running.

`**<%=raw @post.frontend %>**` this line is only running the frontend like css and html but not ruby code

Example:

```
**@post.frontend = 
"<% @fake_post.map do |simple| %>
<h1> <%= simple.description %> </h1>
<% end %>"**
```

Output:

```
**<% @fake_post.map do |simple| %>
<%= simple.description %>
<%= simple.description %>
<% end %>**
```

When I am printing the value like <%= puts @post.frontend %> its throwing undefined template error.

Let me know if I am missing something

Comment: Is there is way I can run this from server side.

Comment: You're basically wanting Erb to do double-evaluation which it doesn't do. You can't just print a string, it has to be evaluated. With the caveat that this is a gaping security risk.

Comment: Yes we can not print a string. But we can convert string so that it can be printed. Similar way the .html.erb files runs the erb code. Is there is a way?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run your template through [`ERB`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) when you want to evaluate your ERB to text.

```
<%= ERB.new(@post.frontend).result_with_hash(fake_post: @fake_post) %>
```

You’ll need to replace `@fake_post` with `fake_post` in your template for this to work.

Note: Allowing users to edit ERB means that you need to trust your users. ERB allows running any Ruby code. Users could add code that exposes their database credentials or changes data in the database or deletes important stuff.

Comment: It should be noted that ERB can run ANY ruby code. And if you're doing this you either need to use complete sandboxing or trust your users 101%. A better alternative is to use a more limited templating language that just does simple replacement.